# Guide/tutorial on how to persistently save data on Spring-Boot with jpa-repositiroies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have googled so much how to save data persistent (meaning it is still there after I shutdown / restart my apllication).
But every guide there is is "Hey we show you how to use spring-boot with jpa real quick and we use h2 database (in-memory)"

I am looking for a guide who shows the setup to make it possible to use a database that stores the data somewhere that it can be retrieved at any later point in time, even after the application was shut down.
If any of you can provide a link to something like this, I am very grateful!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, questions asking for an off-site resource such as a tutorial or a guide are considered off-topic. You can read more about this within the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, the nice part of JPA is that it's database independant. You don't like using an in-memory database? Well, you can set up one, configure the `spring.datasource.url` properly and you're ready to go.

Comment: I understand that and I get downvoted for that, but this " You don't like using an in-memory database? Well, you can set up one, configure the spring.datasource.url properly and you're ready to go." is the part I have never done and thought mabye there is a guide for it

Comment: In that case, Hibernate (= the implementation of JPA Spring boot uses) supports [many different database vendors](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2?_sscc=t). You might have more luck if you look for tutorials about setting up those in stead of looking for all-in-one tutorials that are usually very opinionated.

Answer (score -1):

I think Google can give a lot of examples about that. I am not sure what was your query.
Here are some examples:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-mysql-example/
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

HTH

Comment: thanks, these never popped up. 
I searched for "Spring boot jpa repository persitence", "Spring boot jpa repository save data after exit" etc.  and only guides without persitence were shown